# Max height depending on length of parent div, or div beside it?

Tags: html, css

Here's the problem:

[image: mockup]

Here's what the problem looks like in my application (note, the left bottom column should go to auto scroll at the height of the left column. New data can prepend into either column at any time as well, so the regular javascript method isn't exactly a good way.):

http://i42.tinypic.com/2vbpn5g.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set outer container of this whole with fixed height, make two columns, one for full height box, another for of dynamic height box, with overflow-auto box underneath it.

Otherwise, you will need JavaScript to dynamically set height of boxes in second column, by dividing max height.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing (all 3 sections) in a div and set a max height and no overflow.

Comment: Sure it will. You want the light pink to overflow:auto but the whole containing div to overflow:hidden.

Comment: I haven't been able to get that to work. It doesn't have the scrollbar. (also, I can't really have the containing div with hidden because I have divs that may show up outside of that containing div.

Comment: I have added a photo of what it looks like in my application.

Comment: Build it up on jsfiddle and I'll take a look. jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

left-div : the big div on the left
top-div : top div on the right
bottom-div: bottom  div on the right

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var total_height = $("#left-div").outerHeight();
    var used_height = $("#top-div").outerHeight();
    var free_height = total_height - used_height;

    $("#bottom-div").height(free_height);
});
```